# Are we tied to rekognition when using aws serverless-image-handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, image-processing, amazon-rekognition

I am building a serverless image cropping service for my website and to do so I use the aws serverless solution: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/. It is based on sharpJS for image manipulation and seems to be using Amazon Rekognition for face recognition. My questions is once we install this service, are we tied to using amazon rekognition or is it easy to add my own face detection service to be used by the cropper instead. I know in a last version they Thumbor was used which would have made it easy but they seems to have dropped it in this version. Any insight would be very appreciated :) .

Comment: For this solution you have full access to the source on Github.  It is pretty easy source code to modify for you needs.   However, the Thumbor code is still supported, at least in the code which you can see in the handler code: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/blob/master/source/image-handler/image-request.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am more a python guy so it was not easy for me to browse node code :/. I thought that the mentions of thumbor were to allow for thumbor style queries but not cropping the images using thumbor